# Cannot update password in php

Tags: php, android, mysql, updates

Can someone help me to figure out the problem ? I'm new to `php` and now trying to send the data from android to `MySQL`. I want to update the password based on user's name. I've tried to code but I get error when update `button` is clicked.

```
 public void changePassword(final String name, final String password)
    {
        class UpdateUser extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
            ProgressDialog loading;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(ForgetPassword.this,"Updating...","Wait...",false,false);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(ForgetPassword.this,s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                hashMap.put(Config.KEY_USER_NAME,name);
                hashMap.put(Config.KEY_PASSWORD,password);

                RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();

                String s = rh.sendPostRequest(Config.UPDATE_USER_URL,hashMap);

                return s;
            }
        }

        UpdateUser ue = new UpdateUser();
        ue.execute();
    }
```

**UpdateUser.php**

```
<?php 
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
        //Getting values 

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $pssword = $_POST['password'];


        //importing database connection script 
        require_once('dbConnect.php');

        //Creating sql query 
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET password = '$password' WHERE name = $name;";

        //Updating database table 
        if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
            echo ' Updated Successfully';
        }else{
            echo 'Could Not Update users Try Again';
        }

        //closing connection 
        mysqli_close($con);
    }
?>
```

I get message `Could Not Update users Try Again`.

Comment: Where do you instantiate `$con` ?

Comment: I can't help with the Android stuff, but for PHP/SQL: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()` and make sure the password column is long enough and the right type, that's IF you're using a safe hashing function; doesn't seem like it though.

Comment: In doing that ^ `WHERE name = $name;";` would have thrown you a syntax error. `$name` is a string and must be quoted and error reporting about `$pssword`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I check in URL, nothing is displayed

Comment: Please stop down-voting my question :(

Comment: Write the `$_POST` to the error log. You can check whether the correct values have been received from your app.

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: Noted, with thanks. Will read through the `password_hash()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, had you used error reporting and checking for errors on your query, you would have seen what it would have thrown you, ***errors***.

`WHERE name = $name;";` that needs to be quoted, since it's a string.

`WHERE name = '$name';";`

- Consult: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html

Then, the undefined variable `$password` in your query, where you are assigning it in `$pssword = $_POST['password'];` (or meant to assign it as). But, that could just be a typo on your part.

---

**Passwords**

I also noticed that you may be storing passwords in plain text. This is not recommended.

Use one of the following:

- [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471)
- [`crypt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)
- [`bcrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)
- [`scrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt)
- [**On OPENWALL**](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)
- [**PBKDF2**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)
- [**PBKDF2 on PHP.net**](http://php.net/hash-pbkdf2)
- PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.
- Compatibility pack (if PHP < 5.5) https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/

Other links:

- [**PBKDF2 For PHP**](https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm)

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

and apply that to your code.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

And add `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()`.

This doesn't help you:

```
    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
        echo ' Updated Successfully';
    }else{
        echo 'Could Not Update users Try Again';
    }
```

This will:

```
    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
        echo ' Updated Successfully';
    }else{
        echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($con);
    }
```

---

For the Android code though, I won't be able to help you there, if there are any errors in there.

Also, make sure that you are successfully connected to your database and using the same MySQL API as your query, being `mysqli_`. That is unknown. If you are using `mysql_` or PDO to connect with, then that won't work. You must use the same one from connection to query.

Reference:

- [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php)

Plus, if there are any characters that MySQL will complain about (such as apostrophes), then you will need to escape your data; something you should be doing anyway.

So your code would now read as:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    //Getting values 

    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);


    //importing database connection script 
    require_once('dbConnect.php');

    //Creating sql query 
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET password = '$password' WHERE name = '$name';";

    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
        echo ' Updated Successfully';
    }else{
        echo "Error" . mysqli_error($con);
    }

    //closing connection 
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Comment: @Tony I've already outlined that in comments and in my answer with the reference links. Everything's in there Tony.

Comment: @Tony also, make sure that you are successfully connected to your database and using the same MySQL API as your query, being `mysqli_`. That is unknown. If you are using `mysql_` or PDO to connect with, then that won't work. You must use the same one from connection to query.

Comment: @Tony reload my answer. I can't see how that would fail here.

Comment: Thanks Fred..I will read through all the reference links you gave.

Comment: how do I check the error ? like this `http://localhost/Android/CRUD/register.php` ?

Comment: @Tony No, reload my answer again, I've made a rewrite near the bottom.

Comment: @Tony You're most welcome Tony, *cheers* and all the best in the New Year.

Comment: @Tony Thank you Tony.

Comment: @JohnJoe please don't ask questions in answers or other questions John. Now, I had a look at it, but if Android code is failing, I can't help you with that.

Answer (score 2):

You should add error reporting to your php code and check the logs.

`$pssword = $_POST['password'];`

$password variable is not correctly spelled.

PS: please do not use that code in a production environment, you should never trust user input.

Comment: Did you mean should be  `$sql = "UPDATE users SET password = '$pssword' WHERE name = $name;"` ? I changed it but still cannot update ;

Comment: @Tony that might not be the only issue, but it is visibly wrong by the code you posted. $con might be another cause.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your SQL syntax. The `name` column is I assume a text column so it need quotes around the `$data` i.e. `'$data'`

Also if you output a real error message it will help you solve these issues yourself in future.

And of course the error with setting `$pssword` and using `$password`

```
<?php 
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
        //Getting values 

        $name = $_POST['name'];

        // fix variable name used later
        $password = $_POST['password'];


        //importing database connection script 
        require_once('dbConnect.php');

        //Creating sql query 
        // error here
        //$sql = "UPDATE users SET password = '$password' WHERE name = $name;";
        $sql = "UPDATE users 
                  SET password = '$password' 
                WHERE name = '$name'";

        //Updating database table 
        if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
            echo ' Updated Successfully';
        }else{
            // replace with an actual datbase error output
            //echo 'Could Not Update users Try Again';
            echo mysqli_error($con);
            exit;
        }

        //closing connection 
        mysqli_close($con);
    }
?>
```

> Also when it comes to storing passwords on your database they should really be hashed using the standard php function `password_hash()` [See the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Comment: `unknown column 'Test' in 'where clause'`

Comment: Thats odd, there is not a column named `Test` in that query???? Maybe that error is coming from somewhere else in your code

Comment: Sorry my typo is should be `WHERE name = '$name'";` with single quotes and not backticks.I changed the answer code